# Java: Is corrupt data possible with UDP in Java

Tags: java, networking, udp

I am writing a network test, which sends UDP packets with different sizes (up to 50k bytes). I want to measure ping and package loss. Do I also have to check the data transferred, or is the package dropped if it contains corrupt data?

Comment: What does the javadoc say?

Comment: @Kayaman "Packet delivery is not guaranteed." There is no point about corrupt data.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) sais if the packet arrives, it is correct. UDP does provide checksums to ensure data integrity.

Comment: Not that I needed Wikipedia to know this. It is just one of the first results in Google and I wanted to provide some "further reading" ... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the TCP/IP protocol suite (which includes UDP) is implemented in all modern operating systems. The implementation is often referred to as the *network stack*. The Java virtual machine itself uses regular user-level sockets for its networking, so it uses the operating system's network stack. All you can do from Java is set socket options, specify the source and destination, and provide the data to be sent. So I wouldn't worry about creating malformed packets from Java. The segment (layer 4), packet (layer 3) and frame (layer 2) are all created for your application by the OS. Nothing you can do with regular sockets can change that unless you're using *raw* sockets.

Second, there are multiple error detection codes in each TCP/IP packet. UDP and TCP have a 16 bit checksum code that verifies the header, the packet's payload, and several IP header field. IP packets themselves have a header checksum, and both Ethernet (802.3) and Wifi (802.11) have their own error detection mechanisms at the frame level. The default behavior I've seen in both networking equipment and endpoint operating systems when handling erroneous packets, is dropping them. So there's really very little chance of getting errors in your user-level socket.

Edit:

One point worth mentioning about UDP is that unlike the stream-oriented TCP, UDP sockets operate on a per-packet basis. So whatever you `send()` using a UDP socket, will be sent as a single UDP packet. I'd suggest making sure you don't put anything too big in there at any single point. Don't try to send a big 4KiB chunk as a single packet, because that will cause IP-level fragmentation. Do your best to make sure the packets being sent are at least 20 bytes smaller than the smallest MTU along the path from your machine to your destination (20 bytes is because the IP header is normally 20 bytes long). When in doubt, limit the data sent per packet to about 1000-1200 bytes, well below the common ~1400-1500 MTU limit.